# How to reroute when entering an incorrect URL on address bar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have an Asp.net MVC web application that has at least two controllers. There is a first form when submitted will activate the Create post action method of the first controller(persisting the parent details into db) and then redirect to the Create get action method and then displaying a form to fill in the child entities. This means that I will have to pass the parent Id as a parameter to this controller which I am doing and successfully saving into the child table as a foreign key. My problem is I do not know how to stop someone from entering directly on the address bar the URL to the child form, without the required parent Id that is generated from the parent form(eg https://localhost/controller2/Create). I am thinking of a route that will redirect back to the parent form whenever someone does this, but not sure how in the code.

Comment: Please show code that you have done. Show some effort :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have used `RedirectToAction` within the `Create` method of `Controller1` to redirect to `Create` of `Controller2`

In such a case, if your objective is to prevent access to `Create` of `Controller2`, then you would have to apply some logic within the action itself to check the validity of the parameter that is coming in.

For instance, you are passing the `parentId` as an argument into this GET `Create` method. So you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(string parentId)
{
    if(parentId == null)
    {
        //return some error code like 404 with corresponding error view
    }
    else
    {
        //check if parentId is a valid one and perform the logic as usual
    }
}
```

Comment: The code which I have written above is just to explain what I was trying to say. Since you had not provided with the signature of the action method in the question, I went ahead with this implementation. Idea is to have an `if` condition within the existing action method which checks for `null` in the input parameter. Since your comment suggests that you have an `int` type as the input parameter. You should try changing that to `int?` in order to resolve the error.

Comment: Thanks akg but unfortunately when doing this it gives me an error ('The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(Int32).') When debugging this and putting a breakpoint on start of the Create method of controller2, it does not even hit this meaning there I cannot catch this error as it is happening before the controller loads. This is why I initially thought that it should reroute to controller1 always when user enter this URL manually or if he selected it from the address history list.

Comment: It will be really helpful if you can provide some code sample of how you have implemented the controller1 create method and controller2 create method